# In Linq, How to get list of parents that their children have a special age and other childern remove too?

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have two models: Parent and Child

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Age{get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data:

```
Parent            Child  

ID      Name     ID    Name    Age  ParentID
1       a        1       a1     10     1
2       b        2       a2     20     1
3       c        3       a3     25     1
4       d        4       b1     30     2
5       e        5       b2     35     2
                 6       c1     27     3
                 7       d1     10     4
                 8       d2     18     4
                 9       d3     26     4
                 10      e1     15     5
```

I want to show a list of parents that have any child older than a specific age, and this list would be joined children model, and in children subset, just be showed the one with specific age.

Desired output:

```
parents
ID      Name  Children.ID Children.Name   Age  
1       a        3            a3          25     
2       b        4            b1          30     
3       c        5            b2          35     
4       d        6            c1          27     
                 9            d3          26
```

Note: The children table is in parent's fields.

I tested this code but this showed parents with all children:

```
var parents = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ToList();

  // some processes on parents...

parents = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age >= 25)).ToList();
```

Output:

```
parents
ID      Name  Children.ID Children.Name  Age  
1       a        1                a1     10     
2       b        2                a2     20     
3       c        3                a3     25     
4       d        4                b1     30     
                 5                b2     35     
                 6                c1     27     
                 7                d1     10     
                 8                d2     18     
                 9                d3     26
```

How do I Filter the Children in Linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the related entities as shown in [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include).

```cs
var parents = context.Parents
    .Include(p => p.Children
        .Where(c => c.Age >= 25))
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age >= 25))
    .ToList();
```

---

**Updated:**

As a requirement, you need to retrieve all the `Parent` data and filter after some processing steps. You should iterate each parent and overwrite the `Children` value with the filtered `Children` data.

```cs
var parents = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ToList();

...

parents = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age >= 25)).ToList();

parent.ForEach(p => 
{ 
    p.Children = p.Children
        .Where(c => c.Age >= 25)
        .ToList(); 
});
```

Comment: Excuse me! I didn't explain that the parents list must be contains all data and after some process will be filtered.

Comment: In that case, you can still retrieve all `Parent`s. After your processing step, with a foreach loop to update each parent to filter the data for the `Children`: `parent.ForEach(p => { p.Children =  p.Children.Where(c => c.Age >= 25).ToList(); });`

Comment: This solution is not correct, because the ICollection does not convert to IEnumerable. and when I use to cast, the SQL server throw an exception

Comment: *ICollection does not convert to IEnumerable*, which variable/value do you refer to `ICollection`? `Children`?

Comment: *and when I use to cast, the SQL server throw an exception*, it seems like you are making it as query and retrieving it again from the database. Would be great if you could provide the detailed exception info and the latest code to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. updated answer worked!!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
parents = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age >= 25)).Select(s=>new Parent {
ID=s.ID,
Name=s.Name,
Children= s.Children.Where(c => c.Age >= 25).ToList(),
}).ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this, but the output of this code is like my output, not desired output

Comment: do you want filter childrens too?

Comment: if you whant filter childrens of any parent try this:  parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Age >= 25)).Select(s=>new Parent {
    ID=s.ID,
    Name=s.Name,
Children= s.Children.Where(c => c.Age >= 25).ToList(),
}).ToList()